# Bootstrap modal opens wrong one

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, bootstrap-modal

In my page I got two modals:

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">My title 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        My content 1
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div id="modal2" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">My title 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        My content 2
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I open them with

```
$('#modal1').modal('show');
$('#modal2').modal('show');
```

whenever I need them.

The problem is that no matter what `modalid` is,the first modal is always opened.
I tried to put

```
$('.modal').on('hidden', function(){
    $(this).data('modal', null);
});
```

inside my code,but nothing changed.

(I never show these two modals together.)

I'm using Backbonejs: I open `modal2` when a button is clicked like this:

```
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

events : {
    'click #my_button' : 'show_modal_2'
},

initialize: function(){
    this.render();
},

render: function(){
    var template = my_template; 
    this.$el.html( template );
    $('#modal1').modal('show');
},
show_modal_2 : function(){
    $('#modal2').modal('show');
}

});
```

Modal number 1 is opened when the page is loaded inside `render`.

`modal1` is opened perfectly while `modal2` opens `modal1` when opened.

Comment: You need to show more of the script where `$('#modalid').modal('show');` is called.  A jsfiddle example would be super helpful.

Comment: Should be $('#' + modalid)

Comment: Dont you want to be using "$('modal1')" and "$('model2')?

Comment: Show us more your HTML and JS, where and how you use this modals. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Your code works just as you described it. I don't see any problem with it. Check my fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/abL9qf39/](http://jsfiddle.net/abL9qf39/)

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't show all the relevant code.  `$('#modalid')` clearly won't work for either of them

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: @gyosko roberto's example seems to be working fine... try creating a similar example demonstrating the issue... chances are, you'll find the bug while trying to replicate it in a demo

Comment: can you show how you initialize your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

In my code I build the `modal-body` dynamically like this:

```
$('.modal-body').html(my_html);
```

Problem is I'm changing both modals like this,so `modal2` just looked like `modal1`.
I solved by doing:

```
$('#modal1 .modal-body').html(my_html);
```